# Javadoc @see or {@link}?

Tags: java, javadoc

Could someone tell me the difference between javadoc `@see` and `{@link}`?

Or rather, when to use which of them?

Answer (score 241, accepted):

The [official guidelines](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#inlinelinks) on this are pretty clear.

The functional differences are:

- `{@link}` is an inline link and can be placed wherever you like
- `@see` creates its own section

In my opinion, `{@link}` is best used when you literally use a class, field, constructor or method name in your description. The user will be able to click through to the javadoc of what you've linked.

I use the `@see` annotation in 2 cases:

- Something is very relevant but not mentioned in the description.
- I refer to the same thing multiple times in the description, and it is used as a replacement for multiple links to the same.

I based this opinion on randomly checking out documentation for a great variety of things in the standard library.

Comment: The javadoc does warn that @link is rather intensive and should be used only when necessary.

Comment: For anyone looking, you can get details on this (including the warning about `@link` in the comment above) in [Oracle's Javadoc guide](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-137868.html).

Comment: another way to see it is that {@link} renders as a clickable link, @see is just a text section

Answer (score 53):

`@see` creates an isolated line in the Javadocs. `{@link}` is for embedding within text.

I use `@see` when it's a related entity but I don't refer to it in the expository text. I use links within text when there's tight coupling, or (I feel) it's likely the reader would benefit from the navigation hint, e.g., you'll need to reference it directly.

Answer (score 14):

The `@see` tag is a bit different than the `@link` tag,
limited in some ways and more flexible in others:

[image: different JavaDoc link types]
<sup>*Different JavaDoc link types*</sup>

1. Displays the member name for better learning, and is refactorable; the name will update when renaming by refactor
2. Refactorable and customizable; your text is displayed instead of the member name
3. Displays name, refactorable
4. Refactorable, customizable
5. A rather *mediocre* combination that is:

- Refactorable, customizable, and stays in the **See Also** section
- Displays nicely in the Eclipse hover
- Displays the link tag and its formatting when generated
- When using multiple `@see` items, commas in the description make the output confusing

6. **Completely illegal**; causes unexpected content and illegal character errors in the generator

See the results below:

[image: JavaDoc generation results with different link types]
<sup>*JavaDoc generation results with different link types*</sup>

Best regards.

Answer (score 5):

There's another reference (deprecation section) same [official docs](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#@deprecated) to prefer `{@link}` over `@see` (since Java 1.2):

> For Javadoc 1.2 and later, the standard format is to use @deprecated
>   tag and the in-line {@link} tag. This creates the link in-line, where
>   you want it. For example:
>
> For Javadoc 1.1, the standard format is to create a pair of @deprecated and @see tags. For example: