# What does a # in a comment between class and method mean?

Tags: java, documentation, comments, javadoc

I've started to see class + method references in comments and documentation etc written as:

> MyClass#myMethod

i.e. with a `#` between the class and method. Is this some sort of coding standard/convention?

Comment: yes doing this will allow hyperlinks to be generated in javadoc if it is a javadoc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Official guideline is available at [How to Write Doc Comments for the Javadoc Tool](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html).
Where：

```
@see #field
@see #Constructor(Type, Type...)
@see #Constructor(Type id, Type id...)
@see #method(Type, Type,...)
@see #method(Type id, Type, id...)
@see Class
@see Class#field
@see Class#Constructor(Type, Type...)
@see Class#Constructor(Type id, Type id)
@see Class#method(Type, Type,...)
@see Class#method(Type id, Type id,...)
@see package.Class
@see package.Class#field
@see package.Class#Constructor(Type, Type...)
@see package.Class#Constructor(Type id, Type id)
@see package.Class#method(Type, Type,...)
@see package.Class#method(Type id, Type, id)
@see package
```

To see the difference between @see and @link, please take a look at [Another asked Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097199/javadoc-see-or-link)