# How to reference another method of the same class in Javadoc?

Tags: java, javadoc

Suppose your class has 2 methods:

```
contains() and
containsSame()
```

The distinction between them is subtle and you'd like to mention it as part of Javadoc

In Javadoc, how can you reference a method in the same class, by name?

Comment: possible duplicate of [javadoc: writing links to methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915992/javadoc-writing-links-to-methods)

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Use the `@link` inline tag, and refer to the method with a leading `#`.

```
/**
 * ...
 * This method is similar to {@link #contains()}, with the following differences:
 * ...
 */
public boolean containsSame();


/**
 * This method does ...
 */
public boolean contains();
```

This example only works if there is actually a `contains()` method which has no arguments (which, actually, seems to be not that useful). If you have only a `contains` method with arguments, then either write the argument types in the parentheses:

```
/**
 * ...
 * This method is similar to {@link #contains(Element)}, with the following differences:
 * ...
 */
public boolean containsSame(Element e);

/**
 * This method does ...
 */
public boolean contains(Element e);
```

Or you can omit the parentheses completely:

```
/**
 * ...
 * This method is similar to {@link #contains}, with the following differences:
 * ...
 */
public boolean containsSame(Element e);

/**
 * This method does ...
 */
public boolean contains(Element e);
```

If you have several methods named `contains` (with different parameter lists), this version can't decide which one to use (the link will jump to any of them, hopefully they are all together and do similar things).

Comment: Just an FYI: I was getting a warning with the above answer. Removing the parenthesis on the method fixed them:  {@link #contains}

Comment: @Pytry I guess your method actually had parameters? I updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: *facepalms* ...  You're right that I was. Your expanded explanation is great. Thanks again!