# Is it possible to get the same doc for overloaded methods?

Tags: java, javadoc, overloading

I'm searching the best way to make documentations with overloaded methods.

I have two methods:

```
/**
* does something
* @param A
* @return result
*/
public String methodA(Type1 A);

/**
 * does something
 * @param A
* @return result
*/
public String methodA(Type2 A);
```

Since both methods render the same thing, is it possible to centralize the doc on a method which would take Object arguments? Or is there a better way to do so?

Comment: Are you talking about javadoc?

Comment: You could use generics but I guess this is a bit heavy handed for centralising documentation!

Comment: @ Shreyos Adikari Yes, with JUnit.

Comment: The Javadoc has no such mechanism, no... One has to check for the method arguments.

Comment: Too bad, thanks for the answers anyway.

Comment: You could use the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915992/javadoc-writing-links-to-methods `@link` tag to link one of the methods to the other. This avoids redundancy of the actual documentation ("does something").

Comment: Why the downvote? IMHO this is a reasonable question ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your original intention to write a kind of "generic" documentation does not work out of the box. You need to take care of the parameters and the return value at least.

> Or is there a better way to do so ?

To avoid redundancy of the actual documentation, you can use the [@link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#link) tag.

This is especially useful if the method requires a lot of documentation, like for example the [Properties.load()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.InputStream%29) methods.