# How to create link in Java-Doc?

Tags: java, javadoc

I want to create a link in Java-Doc for my methods and classes. Some methods use objects of another class. So I want to specify the link in the `Java-Doc` so that when user clicks on it, it'll open that class directly.

I've tried with anchor `<a>` tag inside comment, but it dosent work.

How to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [javadoc: writing links to methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915992/javadoc-writing-links-to-methods)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@link`. Something similar like below:

```
/**
 * Links another class {@link com.package.ClassName}.
 */
```