# Javadoc @link different return-types

Tags: java, hyperlink, javadoc

The Javadoc of `@link` is pretty well explained in [the two answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915992/how-to-reference-a-method-in-javadoc), as well as in their given links.
I have one question though: How can you distinguish the different return-type of an otherwise similar method?

Let's say I have the following two methods:

```
public String doSomething(){
   ...
}

public int doSomething(){
   ...
}
```

And at another method I want to `@link` to just the `int doSomething()`. If there was only one `doSomething()` method, the link would be something like:

```
/*
 * ...
 * {@link com.example.package.MyClass#doSomething()}
 */
public void anotherMethod(){
   ...
}
```

Both how can I distinguish the different return-type in the `@link`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have such methods since Java method signature includes method name and argument types and not result's type.

Suppose you have different situation: one method name, but different arguments. In that case method link should include argument types.

```
/**
* This is {@link #doSomething(String)}
*/
public void doSomething(String string){
   ...
}

/**
* And this is {@link #doSomething(int)}
*/    
public void doSomething(int integer){
   ...
}
```

Comment: Ah, you're completely right!.. I was adding some links to some methods in a class, and noticed I had two of the same methods with different return-types, but it turned out to be different names (one character difference, I've renamed one so the difference is easier to spot now).. I could use a vacation.. Thanks again. I'm almost tempted to delete my stupid question, but I'll let you have the rep of your answer instead. :)