# Javadoc @link not working when referencing a vararg (String[]...)

Tags: java, javadoc

I'm trying to generate a Javadoc for my project, but I can't seem to find how to create a link to a precise Method :

```
public static Html select(Buffer<String> contentBuffer, String id, String name, String classes, boolean isMultiple, String[]... attributeList)
```

I tried :

```
{@link #select(Buffer, String, String, String, boolean, String:A...) select()}
{@link #select(Buffer, String, String, String, boolean, String[]...) select()}
```

But there are no link created at all ... I get the error `error: unexpected text` on the link tag.

Am I missing something?

*EDIT : I already know how to form a valid `{@link}`, but for some reason, it doesn't work here ...*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reference a method in javadoc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915992/how-to-reference-a-method-in-javadoc)

Comment: @GeorgHenkel : As you can clearly see, I already followed the rules of the `{@link ...}` in my attempts to solve my problem. Why would you link me this ? ...

Comment: `{@link #select(Buffer, String, String, String, boolean, String[]...)}` seems good to me

Comment: @oleg.cherednik It seemed good to me too, but I always get the same error.

Comment: You may use an IDE that is capable of generating javadoc. They will suggest all possibilities with correct syntax in drop-down boxes and stuff like that. Very convenient.

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: Ok, sorry you are right. In Eclipse your example works.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse but the project isn't local, I'm using the Remote System Explorer to work. So the project isn't really considered as an Eclipse Project, just files packed together. So I can't use any functionality related to an Eclipse Project.

Comment: What is you JDK version?

Comment: @yegodm I am running the v1.8.0_60

Comment: It might be a bug with 1.8 - with 1.8.0_162 I sort of get invalid link too. With 9.0.1 the link is properly generated.

Comment: @yegodm Well that's a bummer ... I guess I'll have to create the link manually then ...

Comment: Do you really want an array of array of `String`? Then you can try changing the `attributeList` parameter reference in the `@link` from `String[]...` to `String[][]`. Seems it works with jdk8.

Comment: Might be a regression of https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=5006659

Comment: No, I can't, I need a vararg. But I'll try to link it as a [][] in the Javadoc, to see if it works

Comment: @yegodm `String[][]` works for the vararg ... You can post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java-8 (possibly due to a regression of a [very old javadoc bug](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=5006659)) a `@link` declaration does not render link properly when the fragment part of the link URL uses ellipsis `"..."` to denote the varargs parameter. Instead the array syntax should be used. So your link declaration

```
{@link #select(Buffer, String, String, String, boolean, String[]...) select()}
```

should be changed this way:

```
{@link #select(Buffer, String, String, String, boolean, String[][]) select()}
```

Also note, that in java-9 the bug is not reproducable.

Answer (score -2):

Shouldn't it be `{@link #select(Buffer, String, String, String, boolean, String[]...) select}` ?