# How to refrence to a method or a block in c commenting

Tags: java, c, comments

I know that we can use comments to refer to e.g. methods in `java` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915992/how-to-reference-a-method-in-javadoc)).

Is this option available in `c` too? Lots of time while commenting, for example, I have a bug that is handled after 10 lines. How can I say to the other developer: "Do not handle it. It's handled on the next 'if()' block"?

```
int main(){
    int x = 10;
    printf("x = %d\n", x); //don't check if x is more than 18. We will check it in another "if"
    
    //bla bla bla
    //...
    
    if(x >= 18)
        printf("OK we can submit you\n");
    else {
        printf("No. You're too young\n");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, in java that works only when generating the documentation, it doesn't link to the method in the source code.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Thanks, but this kind of commentings is still usable when we `ctrl`+`click` on the comment in some IDEs. Better than nothing.

Comment: Note that these links cannot link to some random line number. You can reference "a module, package, class, or member name", but not to "the code 10 lines down".

Comment: So are you asking if and how a certain IDE can jump to certain locations from a comment in source code?

Comment: You can use Javadoc for C sources, with only few limitations. But the common tool is Doxygen that knows many languages. It is quite compatible to Javadoc, if you use "@" instead of "\".

Comment: @ThomasKläger What about a special block? Not 10 lines downs, but a special e.g. `while` or `if`, which has a special comment or what.

Comment: @thebusybee yes. I use VS Code. I know java supports this feature in commenting, so other IDEs which support java, support this too.

Comment: @thebusybee Thanks, but for what I do, I have 2 options: KEIL, VS code. I do microcontroller stuff.

Comment: In JavaDoc the smallest referenceable unit is a "member" of a class: a constructor, a method or a field. You cannot address any smaller unit (i.e. neither line of code nor a block of code within a constructor or method)

Comment: You can use Doxygen with VS code (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cschlosser.doxdocgen) and with Keil IDE (https://www.programmerall.com/article/67281040825/)